# Using Entity Framework fill a combo box removing nulls

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox filled with the below code

```
using (ResiduesFormsEntities entities = new ResiduesFormsEntities())
        {
            Test.ItemsSource = entities.DataTable1.ToList();
            Test.DisplayMemberPath= "Administrator";
            Test.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

        }
```

The problem is not all the columns in DataTable1 are the same size, so there are lots of nulls populating the combobox. How would I alter my code to have a condition similar to

```
WHERE stType IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `entities.DataTable1.Where(entity => entity.stType != null).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into Linq (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). Its a framework for use on lists of information. EF is built to be used with linq. All you need to do is:

```
entities.DataTable1.Where(e => e.YourColumn != null).ToList();
```

This will actually be converted into SQL which will contain your `WHERE` clause. The `e => e...` part is called a Lambda expression (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).